# How do I stop enity framework for trying to connect to database in App_Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am building a web application including Entity Framework. In my solution I have 2 projects. 1 project for Data Access which contains my DbContext class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("MyContext")
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);

        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

and another project for setting up the WebApi I want to use and also contains a web.config. In my web.config I have a connection string looking like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=ServerPcName\SqlServerName;Initial Catalog=UCP;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The connection string should be correct. I retrieved my connection string by following the next steps. First I opened the Server explorer (Views -> Server explorer) and in the server explorer I set up the connection to my database. Next I did right mouse click on my connection and clicked "Modify connection...". In the dialog I clicked on the button "Advanced...". In the next dialog I selected the connection string in the lowest edit box and paste it into my web.config.

Now I try to update my database with the next command:

```
Update-Database -StartUpProjectName WebServices
```

This command returns the next error:

```
Directory lookup for the file [rootpath]\App_Data\UcpContext.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

It looks like to me that it tries to connect or create a database that suppose to be in the ASP.NET folder App_Data but I want Entity Framework to connect to my server. What am I doing wrong here or what is causing the issue that Entity Framework doesn't see or want to use my connection string properly?

Comment: "my web.config" - it's not clear which of the two you're referring to.

Comment: The web.config I am referring to is the one in my startup project

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, and only if I remember correctly, I had put the connection string in the wrong web.config. I also had a project named website where all the front end stuff is in it (html/javascript/angularjs and such) and there was also a web.config file. But that one was clearly the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different string in the constructor:

```
base("name=MyContext")
```

Comment: That gives me a different error: No connection string named 'UcpContext' could be found in the application config file. Probably he is looking in the app.config in my data access project now?